# Components inside components VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to VueJs and I'm having trouble with the following (excuse me in advance if the question seems dumb but I haven't found an answer to this yet):

```
var data = {
        info: [
            {
                brand: 'Samsung',
                model: 'A9834',
                color: 'black',
                id: 0
            },
            {
                brand: 'Nokia',
                model: 'Z9234',
                color: 'blue',
                id: 2
            }
        ]
    }

    Vue.component('list-group', {
        template: '<ul class="list-group"><list-group-item v-for="item in info" v-bind:key="item.id" v-bind:properties="item"></list-group-item></ul>'
    })

    Vue.component('list-group-item', {
                template: '<li class="list-group-item">{{properties.brand}}, {{properties.model}}, {{properties.color}}</li>',
                props: ['properties']
    })

    var instance = new Vue({
        el: '.app', 
        data: data
    })
```

What I'm trying to do with the snippet above is render the  component inside the  component. The error I get in the console is the following:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "info" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

As you can see, what I expect to get is two **li** elements inside a **ul** element (2 elements because I'm looping data.info with a v-for, and data.info has two elements for simplicity); but instead i'm getting the error above. There is obviously something I'm missing here knowledge-wise but I don't know what it is. If you could help me figure it out, I would appreaciate it a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to define the props on `'list-group'` as well: `props: ['info']`.

Comment: Alright. I tried doing what you suggested. The error disappeared, and the <ul> element renders, but it's empty... it doesn't render any <li> element. I updated the list-group component to this: `Vue.component('list-group', {
   template: '<ul class="list-group"><list-group-item v-for="item in info" v-bind:key="item.id" v-bind:properties="item"></list-group-item></ul>',
   props: ['info']
  })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine with `props: ['info']`
https://codepen.io/bsalex/project/editor/ApjgQd#

```
var data = {
  info: [
    {
      brand: "Samsung",
      model: "A9834",
      color: "black",
      id: 0
    },
    {
      brand: "Nokia",
      model: "Z9234",
      color: "blue",
      id: 2
    }
  ]
};

Vue.component("list-group", {
  props: ["info"],
  template:
    '<ul class="list-group"><list-group-item v-for="item in info" v-bind:key="item.id" v-bind:properties="item"></list-group-item></ul>'
});

Vue.component("list-group-item", {
  template:
    '<li class="list-group-item">{{properties.brand}}, {{properties.model}}, {{properties.color}}</li>',
  props: ["properties"]
});

var instance = new Vue({
  el: ".app",
  template: '<list-group :info="info">',
  data: data
});
```

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. I open the codepen link you put above, and indeed it works!. I was playing around with my snippet and with the ideas the commenter above gave me and modified the snippet to look like this: [https://jsfiddle.net/iektop/g0pex00b/](https://jsfiddle.net/iektop/g0pex00b/) . I used data() inside the 'list-group' component to return the same global data variable and registered a props with 'information'. I did this because i though there was a scoping problem and now it works this way too. ideas?

Comment: There are two problems in your fiddle.

1) `props: ['information'],` you are defining prop `information` here, but then you are using prop `info` in your template `v-for="item in info"`  
2) You are not passing data in to your component in your template `<list-group></list-group>`. Here is the fixed fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cnrortqk/1/

Comment: Again, I'm even more confused here. I understand what you say when you mentioned above that I am defining an `information` property and using `info` in my template. But that's why I'm returning a `data` object from the `data()` function in my 'list-group' component. I am returning a `data` object which has an `info` property (an array) which will be used by `v-for="item in info"`. Doesn't that make sense? Also, I ran the fiddle and I see the output rendered. Do you mean you can't see output or I'm doing something innecessary?

Comment: If you are using `data` function in `list-group` - then why do you need `props: ['information']` there? And then why do you pass the same `data` to your app at the bottom `data: data`?

Comment: Understood. `[information]` and `data:data` are not being used at all. But using `data(){ return data;}` seemed to fix the problem because (correct me if I'm assuming something wrong here) now the `info` array will be in scope for the whole `list-group` component, hence, in scope for the `list-group-item` child component and now I'm not seeing any errors in the console. But I'm still curious about the following.... is there a better way to do this ? and why running your codepen link will show me the output i want but if i run it on my machine locally, nothing happens (although no errors).

Comment: Yes, correct.  But `hence, in scope for the list-group-item child component.` - it is not because of the `data()` function, but because you are passing the data fields to the child component with `v-bind:properties="item"`

Comment: `it is not because of the data() function, but because you are passing the data fields to the child component with v-bind:properties="item`. Ok. But, that's precisely what I used the `data()` function for (without it I keep getting the original error I got). I return from that function the `data` object that contained the `info` array. `item` is just the current element in the array iteration using `v-for="item in info"`.

Comment: @Ariel is everything clear? Could you mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Yeah. Everything is fine, thanks for the help. Where do i cloase the question?